# Run-error 1004 -- ActiveSheet.Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I've recorded this macro, it keeps bugging on the ActiveSheet.Paste. Can someone help me please?

thank you

```
Sub Macro13()
'
' Macro13 Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$L$10001").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="O/S"
Columns("A:E").Select
Range("A2").Activate
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$L$10001").AutoFilter Field:=6
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 89.25
Range("G7").Select
Windows("Test.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveSheet isn't the full object to paste into.  Sheets().Range().Paste.

Comment: Hi Cyril, i edited it , it still dont work. Can you please help with more details?

Comment: What are you trying to `Paste` exactly ? you need to have the line of `Copy` and the line of `Paste` without any lines in the middle using `AutoFilter` for instance, or `Workbooks.Add`. If you tell us better what you are trying to achieve, perhaps we can offer a more suitable and robust solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) which is absolutely necessary to follow strictly if you are a beginner. This makes your code a lot faster and cleaner.
Yes I know this is a recorded macro, and yes they always have a lot of `.Select`. This is why you should always re-write your recordings to get a good clean and reliable code. But recordings are good to have something to start with.

Then it is better to specify a worksheet by its name and avoid `ActiveSheet` where ever you can.

Also always specify a worksheet for **every** `Range()` or `Cells()` etc. Otherwise Excel guesses which worksheet you mean and Excel might guess something different from your guess and then fails.

So the code you tried would better look like this …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoMyStuff()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet 'better specify sheet by name: Set wsSrc = Worksheets("SheetName")

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = Workbooks.Add().Worksheets(1) 'get first worksheet of a new added workbook

    wsSrc.Range("$A$3:$L$10001").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="O/S"
    wsSrc.Columns("A:E").Copy wsNew.Range("A1") 'copy from source sheet directly into the new sheet

    wsNew.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    wsNew.Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 89.25
End Sub
```

Comment: It works now ! thank you . but i have another issue. i get this message "The picture is too large and will be truncated” when closing file. PLease help

Comment: @RicarmaniArmani Try a `Application.CutCopyMode = False` in the end.

Comment: @RicarmaniArmani Then see here: [Excel 2013: “The picture is too large and will be truncated.”](https://superuser.com/questions/724467/excel-2013-the-picture-is-too-large-and-will-be-truncated)

Comment: @Peh, i uninstall TeamViewer and add  Application.CutCopyMode = False after as you asked. It still gives me the same error message. Thank you ahead for the help.